# Passing variable when redirecting to a page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have designed a contact page with the inputs validation, if the validation has successfully passed then email be will be sent. I am having problem after email has been sent, the $sent variable is not passing through to the blade view to confirm the user?

In the contact.blade.php file,

```
@if (isset($sent) && $sent == true)
<p>Your details have been successfully send to us we will contact you shortly.</p>
@endif
```

In the controller, show a `/contact` page (GET)

```
   public function showContact()
    {
        $data = [];

        return View::make('contact')->withData($data);
    }
```

In the controller, when user pressed a Submit button (POST)

```
public function postContact()
{

    $contactRules = [
        'contact_name'    => 'required',
        'contact_email'   => 'required|email',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $contactRules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/contact')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $emailData['contact_name'] = Input::input('contact_name');
    $emailData['contact_email'] = Input::input('contact_email');

    Mail::send('emails.contact', $emailData, function ($message) {
        $message->to('email@domain.net', 'Name Name')->subject('Subject Here');
    });


    // Problem Here - $sent varible not passing through to view to confirm user?    
    return Redirect::to('/contact')->with('sent', true);

}
```

After email has been sent, it will redirect back to a `/contact` page but `with('sent', true);` is not passing through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get data use typical `Session::get();`

```
Session::get('sent');
```

here is the [Laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects)

doc says,

> Note: Since the with method flashes data to the session, you may retrieve the data using the typical Session::get method.

---

how `withErrors` works.
here is the [Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation)

it says,

> However, notice that we do not have to explicitly bind the error messages to the view in our GET route. This is because Laravel will always check for errors in the session data, and automatically bind them to the view if they are available.

Comment: Ah ok. I wonder why `->withErrors($validator)->withInput();` would work  when redirecting but can't use own variable?

Comment: Would you use Session::get('sent') in the controller (GET method) or in a view?

Comment: Personally, I check my `Session::get("whatever")` in the a View.

Comment: in the `blade view`, i updated the answer with something regarding to `withErrors`.